# Double Row Header in R

Tags: r

**I am new to using R and need to use it for research purposes in school. I am self taught with only a couple coding classes (none in R). I am working on Accounting reseach that requires me to pull down the S&P 500, S&P 600, and S&P 400 current companies as well as all the changes since 2017. Wikipedia has these tables so my advisior tasked me with writing code to scrape the data tables. I have muddled my way through most of it and can bring the tables in for the current companies but when I go to pull the table of changes I run into issues because there are two rows of headers over the columns and some of the cells are merged (not sure if this is causing the issue or not) but I can't seem to get the first two rows as headers, the second one comes in as data which is incorrect. I will include my code as well as a screenshot of what I am getting and what I am trying to use. Please remember this is my first code in R so it may not be pretty and I am open to any feedback to make this easier. Thank you for your help.

```
#extract s&p 600 changes

#Loadlibraries
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#target webpage containing table you need
url600 <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_600_companies"

#read the html content of the webpage
html_content <- read_html(url600)

#extract the table using the CSS selector
table600changes <- html_content %>%
html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
'[['(2)

#second table
data <- table600changes

#Extract the first two rows as headers
headers <- paste(data[1, ], data[2, ], sep = "_")

#Remove the first two rows from the data
data <- data[-c(1, 2), ]

#Set the extracted headers to the data frame
colnames(data) <- headers

#check table content and overview
head(data)

#view data table
print(data)
```

I have looked here, GitHub, ChatGPT, and even googled for help. So far I have not been able to fix it using the solutions provided on other threads, I think this is because the data isn't coming from a CSV but it is coming from a webpage. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMgdd.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COIAZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, Hilary. Your question has a sense of despair, so I suggested a solution without further ado. For future questions, please examine: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the part about reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as this will make it much easier for others to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to remove the first row. The whole thing can be done in a single pipeline.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

data <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_600_companies" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  '[['(2) %>%
  '['(-1,) %>%
  setNames(c("Date", "Ticker_added", "Security_added",
             "Ticker_removed", "Security_removed", "Reason"))
```

Resulting in

```r
print(data)
#> # A tibble: 223 x 6
#>    Date          Ticker_added Security_added              Ticke~1 Secur~2 Reason
#>    <chr>         <chr>        <chr>                       <chr>   <chr>   <chr> 
#>  1 July 3, 2023  FTRE         Fortrea Holdings            SENEA   Seneca~ FTRE ~
#>  2 July 3, 2023  PHIN         PHINIA                      LOCO    El Pol~ PHIN ~
#>  3 June 23, 2023 ABR          Arbor Realty Trust          ROCC    Ranger~ ABR r~
#>  4 June 19, 2023 DISH         Dish Network                CUTR    Cutera~ DISH ~
#>  5 June 19, 2023 NAVI         Navient                     ZUMZ    Zumiez  NAVI ~
#>  6 June 19, 2023 SITM         SiTime                      GCO     Genesco SITM ~
#>  7 June 19, 2023 MAC          Macerich                    BOOM    Dynami~ MAC w~
#>  8 June 19, 2023 VSCO         Victoria's Secret           GCI     Gannett VSCO ~
#>  9 June 19, 2023 DEI          Douglas Emmett              LPSN    LivePe~ DEI w~
#> 10 June 19, 2023 FULT         Fulton Financial Corporati~ RYAM    Rayoni~ FULT ~
#> # ... with 213 more rows, and abbreviated variable names 1: Ticker_removed,
#> #   2: Security_removed
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Kind of makes me wonder if the should be a read function that handles multi-line headers.

Comment: `unheadr::mash_colnames()`: https://github.com/luisDVA/unheadr

Answer (score 1):

```
#https://github.com/luisDVA/unheadr
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

data <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_600_companies" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) |>
  magrittr::extract2(2) |>
  unheadr::mash_colnames(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


## select elements with CSS class 'wikitable'
## which gets the 'real' data tables from the page:
the_tables <- 
  read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_600_companies') |>
  html_nodes('.wikitable')

## get the second of the two tables and convert to data frame
table_changes <- the_tables[[2]] |> html_table()

## collate original header and first row:
names(table_changes) <- sprintf('%s (%s)', 
                                names(table_changes),
                                table_changes[1,]
                                )

table_changes  <- table_changes[-1,]
```

```
> table_changes
# A tibble: 223 x 6
   `Date (Date)` `Added (Ticker)` `Added (Security)`          `Removed (Ticker)`
   <chr>         <chr>            <chr>                       <chr>             
 1 July 3, 2023  FTRE             Fortrea Holdings            SENEA             
 2 July 3, 2023  PHIN             PHINIA                      LOCO              
 3 June 23, 2023 ABR              Arbor Realty Trust          ROCC              
 4 June 19, 2023 DISH             Dish Network                CUTR              
 5 June 19, 2023 NAVI             Navient                     ZUMZ              
 6 June 19, 2023 SITM             SiTime                      GCO               
 7 June 19, 2023 MAC              Macerich                    BOOM              
 8 June 19, 2023 VSCO             Victoria's Secret           GCI               
 9 June 19, 2023 DEI              Douglas Emmett              LPSN              
10 June 19, 2023 FULT             Fulton Financial Corporati~ RYAM              
# i 213 more rows
```